# How to check brakes on Opel Corsa B 1.3, 1998 model, sedan

Tags: opel, corsa, brake-pad, inspection

I suspect I may have reached the end of my Opel Corsa B's brake shoe/pad life. Over the last few drives the breaks feel a little less effective. A little more slippery/harder. I can feel a slight increase in vibration coming through the brake pedal.

I have never done a brake-check or brake-change before, so how can I check to see what needs repair/replacement? And do I start with the front or back? Do I need to check both front and back brakes?

I will be using a hydraulic floor-jack, and jack-stands to raise/keep the vehicle raised while I remove the wheels.